# How to capture referrer URL on Telegram channel - group using Python - Bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to perform some automation on a telegram channel and/or group using bot, one of the main features I need to use is capturing the referring URL and make some conditions based on that (In order for and action to be performed the user must come from a specific URL)
Again, by referring URL, I mean the website the user will come from, for example I give some authorizations for users coming from my website.
This is the concept, I wish to get guidance on how to achieve it.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! To get a helpful answer, you'll have to provide more context for your question. E.g. what do you mean by a "referring URL"? Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Telegram does not capture what URL did the user open `t.me` links to start a conversation with your bot. What you can do however, is to utilise Telegram's [deep linking functionality](https://core.telegram.org/bots#deep-linking) with one-time auth codes that you generate. The idea is this:

1. Your website generates a one time code that is assigned to a specific user
2. Present the link to your user start a conversation with your bot using the link: `https://t.me/yourbot?start=aXsVB231278G` (the random string is the one time code)
3. When your bot receives the message, it sees it as `/start aXsVB231278G`. You can then extract that code and verify with your website's backend if it is a valid code.

The tokens should be short lived and ideally add an additional layer of verification as anyone (like me above) can craft random payloads to send to the bot.